# Validation of a substring

Tags: java, substring

I have this program that asks the user to input a time in a military time format. It takes the input as XX:YY. It takes the index's of XX as a substring, converts them to integers, and then assigns them to an "hours" instance variable. It does the same with YY to a "minutes" instance variable.

The problem is that I'm putting in case data that is supposed to be false, but it's allowing it when it shouldn't. I know that the mathematics and validation is not wrong, because my professor is the one who made it.

For example, I put in 15:78, which is supposed to get an error. First it checks hours:

```
if(hours > 23)
            {
                System.out.println(militaryTime +
                    " is not a valid miliary time." );
            }
```

And we can see that hours is infact less than or equal to 23 so it's acceptable. However, it's supposed to not allow the minutes as per the minutes check:

```
else if(minutes > 59)
            {
                System.out.println(militaryTime +
                    " is not a valid miliary time." );
            }
```

Where my minutes are clearly over 59 and thus supposed to be declared invalid. But it doesn't. Rather it accepts it and moves on to the mathematics and when it converts it to non-military time, it gives me:

```
Enter a miitary time using the ##:## form   15:78
1:07 AM
```

I think the problem relies in my substring work. I'm still a beginner but my theory is that it's not considering both values in Y-1 and Y-2 as together, but separate. 78 together would > 59, but I don't think it's putting them together.

I'm not sure what I can do to eradicate this issue.

Here's the substring, conversion, and assignment I have set up.

```
//SEPARATE THE STRING INTO THE HOURS
            //AND THE MINUTES, CONVERTING THEM TO
            //INTEGERS AND STORING INTO THE
            //INSTANCE VARIABLES
        hours = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring(0, 1));
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring(3, 4));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `substring` function in Java excludes the second index. So you want

```
    hours = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring(0, 2));
    minutes = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring(3, 5));
```

Quoting from the [API document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the
>   character at index endIndex - 1.

Comment: It crashed when I had it like that the first time, might of been a bug I fixed earlier. So, like on that hours line. It doesn't count the index at 2, just stops at it? Same with 5 on minutes?